# Regex in Python returns nothing (search parameters keywords for search for when using regex)

Tags: python, regex

I'm not so sure about how regex works, but I'm trying to make a project where (haven't still set it up, but working on the pdf indexing side of code first with a test pdf) to analyze the mark scheme pdf, and based on that do anything with the useful data.

Issue is, is that when I enter the search parameters in regex, it returns nothing from the pdf. I'm trying iterate or go through each row with the beginning 1 - 2 digits (Question column), then A-D (Answer column) using `re.compile(r'\d{1} [A-D]')`  in the following code:

```
import re
import requests
import pdfplumber
import pandas as pd


def download_file(url):
    local_filename = url.split('/')[-1]
    
    with requests.get(url) as r:
        with open(local_filename, 'wb') as f:
            f.write(r.content)
        
    return local_filename



ap_url = 'https://papers.gceguide.com/A%20Levels/Biology%20(9700)/2019/9700_m19_ms_12.pdf'
ap = download_file(ap_url)

with pdfplumber.open(ap) as pdf:
    page = pdf.pages[1]
    text = page.extract_text()


#print(text)

new_vend_re = re.compile(r'\d{1} [A-D]')

for line in text.split('\n'):
    if new_vend_re.match(line):
        print(line)
```

When I run the code, I do not get anything in return. Printing the text though will print the whole page.

Here is the PDF I'm trying to work with: https://papers.gceguide.com/A%20Levels/Biology%20(9700)/2019/9700_m19_ms_12.pdf

Comment: I recommend [Kodos] (http://kodos.sourceforge.net/) which is very old (Python 2.5) but still provides reliable support for debugging regular expressions in Python.

Comment: Just being curious why this would be better than services like [regextester](https://www.regextester.com/), [regex101](https://regex101.com/) or [regexr](https://regexr.com/)?

Comment: @js-on I mean I was searching for any way to extract text from a PDF, so I went on this youtube video that used this method, but I do not have deep understanding on the module itself. Is there any other recommended module to be used, it will be highly appreciated!

Comment: This was not meant for you, but BoarGules.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're matching only one single space between the digits and the marks, but if you look at the output of `text`, there is more than one space between the digits and marks.

```
'9700/12  Cambridge International AS/A Level – Mark Scheme  March 2019\nPUBLISHED \n \nQuestion  Answer  Marks \n1  A  1\n2  C  1\n3  C  1\n4  A  1\n5  A  1\n6  C  1\n7  A  1\n8  D  1\n9  A  1\n10  C  1\n11  B  1\n12  D  1\n13  B  1\n...
```

Change your regex to the following to match not only **one**, but **one or more** spaces:

```py
new_vend_re = re.compile(r'\d{1}\s+[A-D]')
```

See the answer by alexpdev to get to know the difference of `new_vend_re.match()` and `new_vend_re.search()`. If you run this within your code, you will get the following output:

```
1  A  1
2  C  1
3  C  1
4  A  1
5  A  1
6  C  1
7  A  1
8  D  1
9  A  1
```

(You can also see here, that there are always two spaces instead of one).

//Edit: Fixed typo in regex

Comment: Well it does read it now, but it does not read it correctly, its not aligned with the pdf

Comment: That's because you are using `\d{1}`, so you are only matching lines containing **1** digit. `re.findall(r'\d+\s+[A-D]', pdf.pages[1].extract_text())` works pretty well for me, matching all 28 question/answer sets.

Comment: @js-on Life saver man, one last thing, can I combine the two pages in the pdf or make it enter the second page automatically to reach the second page with the rest of the answers?

Comment: Dunno if I understand you correct, but you can just loop through the pages and add your findings to a list: `for page in pdf.pages: page.extract_text() ...`